# Como fazer dois comandos SQL na mesma linha com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Preciso fazer com que quando o nome do cliente seja editado, além de realizar um UPDATE na tabela de clientes, precisa fazer um UPDATE atualizando em outra tabela todos os registros que já usaram esse cliente, no momento o código está apenas editando o nome do cliente, não consegui fazer executar essas duas ações somente nesse código.

```
$sql = "UPDATE clientes SET cliente_nome=? WHERE id=?";
```

Um exemplo do outro comando que preciso juntar:

```
UPDATE cadastros SET cliente_nome=? WHERE cliente_nome='$cliente_nome'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Para o PHP PDO

Você pode executar multiplas queries com:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);

$sql = "
UPDATE clientes SET cliente_nome=? WHERE id=?;
UPDATE cadastros SET cliente_nome=? WHERE cliente_nome='$cliente_nome';
";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

## Para o PHP MySQLi

A API do PHP não permite isso para prevenir injeções SQL no seu código, como por exemplo inserir um código malicioso, algo como `'; UPDATE users SET admin=1 WHERE username='hacker'`. Por conta disso, é necessário executar uma query por vez dentro do `mysqli_query`.

Mas, existe o `mysqli_multi_query`, que permite executar várias queries separadas por `;`.

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

// isso é necessário! fique atento à ataques de SQL Inject.
$cliente_nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($cliente_nome);

$sql = "
UPDATE clientes SET cliente_nome=? WHERE id=?;
UPDATE cadastros SET cliente_nome=? WHERE cliente_nome='$cliente_nome';
";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    do {
        /* obtém o primeiro resultado da query */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* se tiver mais resultados, coloca uma linha */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

Fique atento que ainda é necessário fazer um escape nas variáveis com `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

---

- [Documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)
- [Documentação do multi query](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: Nossa que excelente resposta! Resposta direta, objetiva e completa, parabéns e muito obrigado!